# Access Equivalents in SQL

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have some code where the data is getting converted `CDbl` in Access but I am rewriting it in SQL and can't figure out what to put in place of it. The code in MS-Access reads:

```
(CASE 
   WHEN EMP_TNG_RL_CD = 'ST' 
   THEN [CountOfEMP_TNG_STT_DT] * CDbl([Length]) 
   ELSE 0 
 END) AS ST_HOURS_SUM
```

Answer (score 5):

In SQL Server you can use:

```
CASE 
  WHEN EMP_TNG_RL_CD = 'ST' 
  THEN [CountOfEMP_TNG_STT_DT] * cast([Length] as float) 
  ELSE 0 
END AS ST_HOURS_SUM
```

See a list of [data types in SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx)

Comment: @user1958651 what is the datatype of `[Length]` in access?

Comment: Is `DOUBLE` even a type in TSQL?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson oops, my fault. I meant float. :)  This is what happens when trying to work during a day off.

Comment: Worked! Thank you for taking time from your day off to help me out.